# Sort array of objects by two properties

Tags: swift, sorting

This has been asked and answered before using `NSSortDescriptor` where it is quite easy. But is there a Swift-standard way using `Array.sort()`?

```
struct Sortable {
    let isPriority: Bool
    let ordering: Int
}
```

Sorting an array of `Sortables` by one property is simple:

```
sort { $0.ordering < $1.ordering }
```

But I want to sort by `isPriority` then by `ordering` - and I can't get my head around a simple statement to make that happen.

Comment: Should we close this question as a dupe, and point to this more popular variant of it? https://stackoverflow.com/q/37603960/3141234

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes there is a very simple way using the `Array.sort()`

**Code:**

```
var sorted = array.sorted({ (s1, s2) -> Bool in
    if s1.isPriority && !s2.isPriority {
        return true //this will return true: s1 is priority, s2 is not
    }
    if !s1.isPriority && s2.isPriority {
        return false //this will return false: s2 is priority, s1 is not
    }
    if s1.isPriority == s2.isPriority {
        return s1.ordering < s2.ordering //if both save the same priority, then return depending on the ordering value
    }
    return false
})
```

**The sorted array:**

```
true - 10
true - 10
true - 12
true - 12
true - 19
true - 29
false - 16
false - 17
false - 17
false - 17
false - 18
```

**Another a bit shorter solution:**

```
let sorted = array.sorted { t1, t2 in 
   if t1.isPriority == t2.isPriority {
      return t1.ordering < t2.ordering 
   }
   return t1.isPriority && !t2.isPriority 
}
```

Comment: This is very good thank you. It can be written more tersely - I will add to your answer.

Comment: My edit to your answer was rejected, so here is the code I used.
`let sorted = array.sorted { t1, t2 in`
    `if t1.isPriority == t2.isPriority {`
        `return t1.ordering < t2.ordering`
    `}`
    `return t1.isPriority && !t2.isPriority`
`}`

Comment: Shouldn't `array.sorted` be `array.sort`?

Comment: @Crashalot yeah. But in old swift it was '.sorted'

Comment: @DejanSkledar makes sense, but perhaps an edit is in order for new Swift users?

Comment: Definitely agree with you. I wouldn't mind an edit suggestion either, since after many answers you get behind updating them all.

Comment: The `&& !t2.isPriority` is not necessary. If you know the priorities are different, just a check for `t1.isPriority` or `!t2.isPriority` will make `&&` with the other redundant.

Answer (score 17):

Here is a simple statement to do this sorting:

```
var sorted = array.sort { $0.isPriority == $1.isPriority ? $0.ordering < $1.ordering : $0.isPriority && !$1.isPriority }
```

Answer (score 2):

Conform to `Comparable`!

```swift
extension Sortable: Comparable {
  static func < (sortable0: Sortable, sortable1: Sortable) -> Bool {
    sortable0.isPriority == sortable1.isPriority
    ? sortable0.ordering < sortable1.ordering
    : sortable0.isPriority
  }
}
```

Which will allow for:

```
sortableArray.sorted()
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a blog post on how to this in Swift 3 and keep the code simple and readable.

You can find it here:

http://master-method.com/index.php/2016/11/23/sort-a-sequence-i-e-arrays-of-objects-by-multiple-properties-in-swift-3/

You can also find a GitHub repository with the code here:

https://github.com/jallauca/SortByMultipleFieldsSwift.playground

The gist of it all, say, if you have list of locations, you will be able to do this:

```
struct Location {
    var city: String
    var county: String
    var state: String
}

var locations: [Location] {
    return [
        Location(city: "Dania Beach", county: "Broward", state: "Florida"),
        Location(city: "Fort Lauderdale", county: "Broward", state: "Florida"),
        Location(city: "Hallandale Beach", county: "Broward", state: "Florida"),
        Location(city: "Delray Beach", county: "Palm Beach", state: "Florida"),
        Location(city: "West Palm Beach", county: "Palm Beach", state: "Florida"),
        Location(city: "Savannah", county: "Chatham", state: "Georgia"),
        Location(city: "Richmond Hill", county: "Bryan", state: "Georgia"),
        Location(city: "St. Marys", county: "Camden", state: "Georgia"),
        Location(city: "Kingsland", county: "Camden", state: "Georgia"),
    ]
}

let sortedLocations =
    locations
        .sorted(by:
            ComparisonResult.flip <<< Location.stateCompare,
            Location.countyCompare,
            Location.cityCompare
        )
```