# Sort array by two properties

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I would like to sort an array, which has multiple properties, by two different properties:

```
@IBAction func returnToMainController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
    if let scr = segue.sourceViewController as? EditViewController
    {
        let newvorname = scr.vornameTextField.text
        let newname = scr.nameTextField.text
        let newadresse = scr.adresseTextField.text
        let newhausnummer = scr.hausnummerTextField.text
        let newpostleitzahl = scr.plzTextField.text
        let newort = scr.ortTextField.text
        let newtelefonnummer = scr.telefonnummerTextField.text
        let newberuf = scr.berufTextField.text

        let newKontakt = Telefonbuch(name: newname!, vorname: newvorname!, beruf: newberuf!, telefonnummer: newtelefonnummer!, adresse: newadresse!, hausnummer: newhausnummer!, plz: newpostleitzahl!, ort: newort!)

        kontaktListe.append(newKontakt)
        kontaktListe.sortInPlace({$0.name < $1.name})
        Telefonbuch.saveArray(kontaktListe)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

In "kontaktliste.sortInPlace({$0.name < $1.name}) I'm able to sort by name. But how can I sort the array by name first, and if two names are the same, then sort by prename?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use conditions inside the sort/sortInPlace closure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530620/sort-array-of-objects-by-two-properties

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, that was what I was looking for.