# Create new "groups" from existing list of groups using date and status

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

So I currently have a list of "pursuits" (shown in the "label" column). I need to break these pursuits into separate instances depending on whether they are active or inactive and how many times they have been active or inactive. I currently have:

```
 datetime                                      title    label   status           option_title
1  2016-08-06 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?      AIG     <NA> 1 - Opportunity Review
2  2016-08-06                            Pursuit status:      AIG   Active                   <NA>
3  2016-08-31 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?      AIG     <NA>    2 - Solution Review
4  2016-12-13 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?      AIG     <NA>    4 - Submit Proposal
5  2016-10-27 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz     <NA>      Pre-Qualification
6  2016-11-14                            Pursuit status:  Allianz   Active                   <NA>
7  2017-05-18 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz     <NA> 1 - Opportunity Review
8  2017-05-18 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz     <NA>      Pre-Qualification
9  2017-08-24                            Pursuit status:  Allianz Inactive                   <NA>
10 2016-10-27 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz     <NA>      Pre-Qualification
11 2016-11-14                            Pursuit status:  Allianz   Active                   <NA>
12 2016-12-19 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz     <NA> 1 - Opportunity Review
13 2017-04-14 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz     <NA>    2 - Solution Review
```

I want to get:

```
 datetime                                      title          label         option_title
1  2016-08-06 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?      AIG - Active1   1 - Opportunity Review
2  2016-08-31 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?      AIG - Active1   2 - Solution Review
3  2016-12-13 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?      AIG - Active1   4 - Submit Proposal
4  2016-10-27 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz - Active1   Pre-Qualification
5  2017-05-18 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz - Active1   1 - Opportunity Review
6  2017-05-18 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz - Active1   Pre-Qualification
7  2016-10-27 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz - Inactive1 Pre-Qualification
12 2016-12-19 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz - Active2   1 - Opportunity Review
13 2017-04-14 What is the current stage of this Pursuit?  Allianz - Active2   2 - Solution Review
```

I'm assuming this could be done in dplyr using the "datetime" field with the "status" field, but I'm unsure how to approach it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As per expectation  it looks like you want to sort list by label & Date. You can call sort function on your array to sort and implement your logic for sorting in block.

Refer [Sort array of objects by two properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530620/sort-array-of-objects-by-two-properties)

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but I don't think this is what I want at all. The "label" field gets completely changed depending on the "status" column, so a sort would not solve this issue.